# PHP If Else Override

Tags: php, if-statement, get

Quick and painless version of my question... I have a querystring that is passed certain variables... How can I prevent the following in the instance of someone freetyping into the querystring?

```
Notice: Undefined index: v in C:\inetpub\ts61\show.php on line 67161
```

I just want to default to a set behaviour if none of the conditions are able to be met.

It seems to be from this call (but I can't be certain):

```
if (($_GET['v']) == NULL){}`
```

In this code:

```
if (!isset($_GET['v'])) {
echo("<script>alert('I'm okay!!!');</script>");
} else {
if ($_GET["v"] == 'a')
{
echo("<script>alert('I'm okay!!!');</script>");
}
elseif ($_GET["v"] == '1')
{
echo("<script>alert('I'm okay!!!');</script>");
}
elseif ($_GET["v"] == '7')
{
echo("<script>alert('I'm okay!!!');</script>");
}
elseif ($_GET["v"] == '14')
{
echo("<script>alert('I'm okay!!!');</script>");
}
elseif ($_GET["v"] == '28')
{
echo("<script>alert('I'm okay!!!');</script>");
}
} 
if (($_GET['v']) == NULL) {
echo("<script>alert('I just errored!!!');</script>");
}
```

I hate using querystrings but the user needs the ability to bookmark...
is this a terrible way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the **if-else** statements, use the **switch-case-default** statements, with which you can define a default value.

Comment: Legend... Thx... stupid lack of sleep forgot about that one!